# My tablet is showing a download of qfota and have tried to stop it and it still continues. What is it?

Tags: tablet, downloading, verizon

tablet is showing a download of Qfota.  What is this?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, constructive and informative question helps us answer them. can you provide a little more information like, tablet model, android version, anything you did to it before the issue started happening that is worth mentioning

Answer (score 1):

The "OTA" is for Over The Air, referring to an update supplied by your mobile carrier.  There's a new version of Android or perhaps a system application update available for your device.  I can't find a lot of information about "qfota" specifically other than that it is for updates from Verizon.